# Reading png as a N x 3 matrix in R

Tags: r, png, pixel

I would like to read a simple black/white picture in png format into R.
I need 3 information for each pixel, the x, y coordinates and color information(0 for white, 1 for black).

I need this information to run a function that checks if there are any closed white elements in the picture or not.

Any tips will be more than welcome.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769628/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-an-image-using-r

Comment: Hi,

I have seen this question.
An there the proposition is to convert to ppm, but I cannot do it outside R.

Comment: sorry didn't get your comment

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be almost trivial if you have `imager` package installed. The color numbers here are inverted, but you should be able to change this without a problem.

```
library(imager)

xy <- load.image("vds9S.png")
head(as.data.frame(xy))

  x y value
1 1 1     1
2 2 1     1
3 3 1     1
4 4 1     1
5 5 1     1
6 6 1     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!